# Haxe: rebuild hxcpp failed with Error: Could not find build target "std"

Tags: haxe, openfl, nme, hxcpp

Trying to rebuild hxcpp failed with the cryptic error message:

```
Error: Could not find build target "std"
```

Answer (score 4):

Some users report this hint (I swear I didn't see it when I hit the issue, unless I'm just blind):

```
Have you tried rebuilding the hxcpp.n and build.n scripts?
This is done by running haxe in the tools/hxcpp and tools/build directories.
```

Hence:

```
cd hxcpp/tools/hxcpp
haxe compile.hxml
cd ../build
haxe compile.hxml
```

Fixes it.

Also note that nightly hxcpp builds are available from [nmehost.com](http://nmehost.com/hxcpp/) and [openfl.org](http://www.openfl.org/builds/hxcpp/) if you just need a newer version than what's available via `haxelib`.